# Append content in div using jQuery('content-id').html

Tags: jquery

Using jQuery, I'm trying to append the content of the WordPress editor with a snippet of html text.

The editor content is contained in a textarea element with id='content'

My Code is:

```
snippet = 'This is the snippet';
jQuery('#content').html(snippet);
```

But nothing happens to the code inside the content editor. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `val` and not `html` for textareas. Try:

```
var e = jQuery('#content');
e.val(e.val() + snippet);
```

**Update:** I did a bit of searching and it appears that WordPress uses the TinyMCE editor. According to their docs, you should be able to simply write:

```
tinymce.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, 'some text');
```

and it will automatically add the text to the active editor. No jQuery required.

Comment: @casablanca why to store in e and again do e.val(e.val()+snippent)

Comment: @gov: The OP wanted to append the snippet to the existing text, so I'm getting the value and adding it to that. Storing the object in `e` saves an extra call to jQuery.

Comment: @casablanca: Awesome! Thanks. Works if the editor is in html mode. Any idea how to paste plain text into Visual editor?

Comment: @Scott B: I'm not familiar with the WordPress editor, but in general, it should work the same in text/HTML mode. What is the problem you're facing?

Comment: The text only gets appended when the editor is in "html" mode. When its in "Visual" mode (wysiwyg), nothing happens.

Comment: Thanks Casablanca. I appreciate that. I'm trying to pass some data pulled from the jQuery.ajax call over to the editor. So it was just easiest to do it in place.

Answer (score 1):

val() instead of html() for form inputs

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery('#content').val(snippet);
```